# Ubuntu 20.04 has no installation candidate for php8.1-sqlite

Tags: 20.04, php, shared-library, sqlite3, php-cli

Apparently package `php8.1` is available for Ubuntu 22.04 but not available for 20.04.  `php7.4-sqlite` is, however, available for 20.04.

In particular I'd like to use PDO with sqlite on PHP8.1 on 20.04.  What are my options to make this happen?

I've already altered `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini` in anticipation of this working.  I found instructions for building `libsqlite3.so` [here](https://vikborges.com/articles/making-php-8-use-the-latest-version-of-sqlite3-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/). And with that, I was able to compile the library.  Then I issued:

```
sudo mv libsqlite3.so /usr/lib/php/20210902/sqlite3.so
```

But when I ran `php -v`, the error log said:

```
[29-Jul-2023 18:26:13 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_sqlite (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_sqlite: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_sqlite.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[29-Jul-2023 18:26:13 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'sqlite3' in Unknown on line 0
```

(This is different from the prior error messages, which were:

```
[29-Jul-2023 18:24:29 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_sqlite (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_sqlite: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_sqlite.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[29-Jul-2023 18:24:29 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlite3' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/sqlite3 (/usr/lib/php/20210902/sqlite3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/sqlite3.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/sqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

(And, yes, I understand that even if that had worked, it likely would not have solved the PDO problem.)  So I'm not sure how I can proceed to get this functionality for PHP8.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.  Is there another package, or maybe a non-standard source from which I can get a working PDO + SQLITE3 (or at least PHP + SQLITE3) installation?  Web searches in this case, with the appropriate keywords, have not helped (other than the afore-mentioned library compilation).  Or maybe the compile option is still valid but there are steps missing?

**EDIT**

This was the sqlite3 library compile command:

```
gcc \
    -Wl,-soname,libsqlite3.so.0 \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_DBSTAT_VTAB \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_TOKENIZER \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4 \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5 \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1 \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_PREUPDATE_HOOK \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_SESSION \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STMTVTAB \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UNKNOWN_SQL_FUNCTION \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UNLOCK_NOTIFY \
    -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT \
    -DSQLITE_HAVE_ISNAN \
    -DSQLITE_LIKE_DOESNT_MATCH_BLOBS \
    -DSQLITE_MAX_SCHEMA_RETRY=25 \
    -DSQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER=250000 \
    -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOOKASIDE \
    -DSQLITE_SECURE_DELETE \
    -DSQLITE_SOUNDEX \
    -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 \
    -DSQLITE_USE_URI \
    -shared \
    -o libsqlite3.so \
    -fPIC \
sqlite3.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install `php8.1` on Ubuntu 20.04, first you will need to add the `ppa:ondrej/php` repository, because PHP 8.1 packages are not in the official repo.

- Add ondrej's repo:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt upgrade
  ```
- Install PHP 8.1:

  ```
  sudo apt install php8.1
  sudo apt install php8.1-cli
  sudo apt install php8.1-sqlite3
  ```
- Tell the system to use 8.1 for the `php` CLI command:

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.1
  ```